# Doctrine ParamConverter using info of related Entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have in Symfony a Entity of `Post`. That project has translations, stored in `PostTranslation`.

Each Post has a slug that is different for each language.

The code looks looks like:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;

/**
 * @I18nDoctrine
 * @Route("/blog/{slug}")
 * @ParamConverter("post", class="SensioBlogBundle:Post")
 */
public function showAction(Post $post)
{
}
```

But how can I do a `findOneBy('slug')` kind of search? Because it is stored in the related Entity.

Answer (score 0):

I guess besides `slug` property your `PostTranslation` entity stores some sort of language/locale, e.g. `locale` property, am I right? I also guess that your website is interlocalized based on some parameter stored in URL (different (sub)domain, query string parameter, path prefix - it's irrelevant), right?

There are at least three solutions that solve your problem:

1. Abandon the use of `ParamConverter` and do everything by yourself.
2. Override [`DoctrineParamConverter`](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Request/ParamConverter/DoctrineParamConverter.php) from [SensionFrameworkExtraBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html) and add support for finding by `slug` and `locale` for `Post` class. I would also suggest creating a little bit more robust solution:

   1. Create `Translatable` interface that defines `getTranslations()` and `setTranslations()` methods and apply it to your `Post` class.
   2. In your `CustomDoctrineParamConverter` check whether requested class implements this interface, if so, it means that you're going to search entity based on its translation, that is `locale` and some locale-unique property.
   3. Now you need some way, to get the name of this locale-unique property. You could create another interface for your `PostTranslation` class that will define a single method, something like `getLocaleIdentifier/UniqueProperty` that for `PostTranslation` will return `"slug"`.
   4. If you know, that you need to find a `Post` property, based on `locale` and `slug` property from its `translations` assocation you can quite easily create DQL query to do that.
3. `ParamConverter` annotation has `repository_method` property that allows you to use custom method from `PostRepository` which should retrieve `Post` entity. The only problem is that built-in `DoctrineParamConverter` will pass only `slug` parameter to this method. Your repository will have to informed about current locale in some way. This could be achieved in many different ways, here's one of them:

   1. Create `LocaleAware` interface with a single method `setLocale($locale)`.
   2. Implement that interface in `PostRepository`
   3. [Create event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) that listens for `kernel.request` event:

      1. Iterate through all Doctrine's repositories.
      2. Check if given repository implements `LocaleAware` interface.
      3. Inject request's `_locale` attribute into repository.

Comment: Code samples would be really helpful and appreciated